# Codeigniter - How to store the test selected answer after pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating a test system, this is my first codeigniter project. I am able to make the pagination, so each page will only display one question and click next button to go next question. Now my problem is when user answer one question and go next but when he/she go back to previous question the answer doesn't appear there. Below are my code:

```
Controller.php
...
$config['per_page'] = 1; 
$page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
$data['question'] = $this->TestModel->getAllQuestion($id, $page);
$data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
$this->load->view('TestView',$data);

TestView.php
<form name="testform" action="" method="post">
    <div class="bs-question">
    <?php
        foreach ($question as $row)
        {
     ?>
        <h3><?php echo $row->question; ?></h3>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div style="padding-left:20px;">
           <?php
             foreach ($answer as $an)
            {
           ?>
            <div class="radio">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="<?php echo $an->aid?>"><?php echo $an->answer ?>
              </label>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <?php
               }
            ?>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <?php echo $links; ?>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

How can I store the selected answer, when user go back previous/next qeustion?

What I do:

```
 $('#next a').click(function () {
                    var link = $(this).get(0).href; // get the link from the DOM object
                    var form = $('#testform'); // get the form you want to submit
                    var segments = link.split('/');
                    // assume the page number is the fifth parameter of the link
                    $('#page').val(segments[3]); // set a hidden field with the page number
                    form.attr('action', link); // set the action attribute of the form
                    form.submit(); // submit the form
                    return false; // avoid the default behaviour of the link
                });
```

In my controller:

```
if($this->input->post('optionsRadios')){
        $s_v = array(
            'questionno'. $this->input->post('qnsid') => $id = $this->input->post('qnsid'),
            'optionsRadios'. $this->input->post('qnsid') => $id = $this->input->post('optionsRadios')
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($s_v); //add the ID to your session
    }
```

In my view:

```
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" <?php if( $this->session->userdata('optionsRadios'.$question->qid) && $this->session->userdata('optionsRadios'.$question->qid) == $row['aid'] ) echo "checked";
else echo ""; ?> value="<?php echo $row['aid']?>">
```

Comment: just keep all the answers in session and load questions with selected answer if exist in session.

Comment: How to keep the selected answer, because when go next button the form haven't submit? Sorry I not very understand.

Comment: When you press the button, you can save the selected answer with question id in session either through page submit or ajax. While loading the prev page, you can load the selected answer based on the question id.

Comment: You could also append the selection to the query string.

Comment: What do you mean append the selection to the query string?

Comment: Hello there, please make pagination as "button" that submits form, in controller create a method that takes care of saving/loading to session, after all is done redirect to question 2 (or simply load question 2 so less redirects are in application). Note that "submitting link" is easily achieved via JavaScript (jQuery). If you find this troubling let me know I'll craft you an example.

Comment: Hi, I've edit the code, it works so far, but could you advice my code. Thank You very much.

Comment: I would change these lines `'questionno'. $this->input->post('qnsid') => $id = $this->input->post('qnsid'),` in this way `'questionno_'. $this->input->post('qnsid') => $this->input->post('qnsid'),` undersquare if you ever need to [`explode()`](http://www.php.net/explode)  , also for better practice try to use `<?= $variable ?>` its nicer than `<?php echo $variable ?>` . What exactly you need advice about?

Comment: Now the code is working, but because only when user click previous and next button will do the session storing. If the user hit the last question, and directly click on submitForm, the last question answer will not be stored.

Comment: You can have two "submit" buttons in one form, so if "submitForm" is clicked load storing  **method** before anything else `$this->store_2_session();` make it as "one" form not two forms. I see only one form in code you've posted. I dont know what else is there to worry about, please make an edit and add full view (last page).

Comment: also suggestion to the last part of your code `<input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" <?= (( $this->session->userdata('optionsRadios'.$question->qid) && $this->session->userdata('optionsRadios'.$question->qid) == $row['aid'] )) ? "checked" : "" ?> value="<?= $row['aid']?>">` use ternary if echoing in view IF/ELSE values it is shorter.